# sequelize: Not include model if where conditon of included model matches

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to get all RecurringEvents that have no excludeDates for today.

I have following models:

Recurring events

```
const RecurringEvent = sequelize.definge('recurringEvent,{
       id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},
       title: Sequelize.STRING
       });
```

And ExcludeDates with a foreign key recurringEventId

```
const ExcludeDate = sequelize.define('exclude_date',{
  id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey:true},
  recurringEventId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  date: Sequelize.DATE
});
```

As a relationship i defined

```
RecurringEvent.hasMany(ExcludeDate, {foreignKey: 'recurringEventId'});
```

I can get all my RecurringEvents including the the excludeDates with

```
RecurringEvent.findAll({include:[{model:ExcludeDate}]});
```

That will give me an output like:

```
[
 {
 "id": 1,
 "title": "Event1",
 "exclude_dates": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2019-02-13",
    "recurringEventId": 1,
  },
 {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2019-02-14",
    "recurringEventId": 1,
  }
]
```

Now i would like to get the Recurring events but only if there is no exclude date for today.

so far i have tried

```
RecurringEvent.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: ExcludeDate,
        where: {
            date: {
                [Op.ne]: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

But that only leaves out the ExcludeDate entry with the current Date like that :

```
[
 {
 "id": 1,
 "title": "Event1",
 "exclude_dates": [
 {
"id": 2,
"date": "2019-02-14",
"recurringEventId": 1,
 }
]
```

How can i exclude the whole RecurringEvent if and ExcludeDate for it is set for today?

**Edit:**

I also read in the docs

> To move the where conditions from an included model from the ON condition to the top level WHERE you can use the '$nested.column$'

So i have tried this:

```
RecurringEvent.findAll({where:{
'$exclude_dates.date$':{
[Op.ne]: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
}
},
include: [{model: ExcludeDate}]
})
```

But without any luck, i'm still getting RecurringEvents just without the one exclude date in the exclude_dates property

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `required: true,` to your include model to make inner join instead of left join. e.g.

```
RecurringEvent.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: ExcludeDate,
        required: true,
        where: {
            date: {
                [Op.ne]: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
            }
        }
    }]
})
```

Comment: Yes i tried that too. Same results. Events still showing up just with all other exclude dates inside the exclude_dates